# Can this code be made more efficient?It doesnt work for larger inputs

Tags: python, loops, time, time-complexity, memory-efficient

#A contains n number of students' skill set in m different skills.The goal is to create a team of two students who have max team rating.Suppose a team has 2 student of skill set[1,2,5] [2,1,2].Together they can answer question of rating [2,2,5].The team rating will be 2 since they can solve 2 rating questions in all skills.#

```
n=int(input())
m=int(input())
A=[]
for i in range(n):
    l=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
    A.append(l)
team_rating=[]
for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(i,n):
        rating=[]
        for k in range(m):
            x=max(A[j][k],A[i][k])
            rating.append(x)
        team=min(rating)
        team_rating.append(team)
print(max(team_rating))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I think the priority here is to getting it to work for any inputs.  Then figure out how to make it efficient.

Comment: I did try it.n=int(input())
m=int(input())
A=[]
for i in range(n):
    l=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
    A.append(l)
team_rating=[]
for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(i+1,n):
        rating=[max(value) for value in zip(A[i], A[j])]
        team_rating.append(min(rating))
print(max(team_rating))

Comment: The two loops are crucial to pair up the teams...but it still isn't efficient

Comment: can you share a link of question?

Comment: maybe you could ask on similar portal [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)